# Passing arguments in nonlinear optimization function `nloptr`

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

My initial question can be found here:[Optimization in R with arbitrary constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611092/optimization-in-r-with-arbitrary-constraints/21612119#21612119)

It led to another question how to pass arguments into `nloptr`.
I need to minimize a function `F(x,y,A)` where `x` and y are vectors and `A` is a matrix, while having constrains that `sum(x * y) >= sum(y/3)` and `sum(x)=1`. 
I have tried to use `nloptr`:

```
F <- function(x,y,A){
   ...
}

Gc <- function(x,y){
  return(sum(y/3) - sum(x*y))
} 

Hc <- function(x){
  retunr(1-sum(x))
}

nloptr(x0=rep(1/3,3), eval_f=F, lb = 0.05, ub = 1, eval_g_ineq = Gc, eval_g_eq = Hc, opts = list(), y=y, A=A)
```

And I receive an error:
`'A' passed to (...) in 'nloptr' but this is not required in the eval_g_ineq function.`

If I say `nloptr( ... , y, A)`

I get:`eval_f requires argument 'cov.mat' but this has not been passed to the 'nloptr' function.`

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there are several things going on here:

First, the objective function, `F`, the equality constraint function, `Hc`, and the inequality constraint function, `Gc`, all have to take the same arguments. So pass `x, y, A` to all three and just ignore them where they are not needed.

Second, you have to define `y` and `A` somewhere...

Third, you must specify which algorithm to use. Do this with `opts=list(algoritm=...)`. It turns out that if you are (a) using constraints, and (b) *not* providing functions to calculate the jacobian matrices, then only some of the algorithms are appropriate. In your case `opts=list(algorithm="NLOPT_GN_ISRES")` seems to work.

Finally, the default `maxeval = 100` which turns out to be not nearly enough. I had to set it to 100,000 to get convergence.

Putting this all together, albeit with a made-up objective function:

```
F <- function(x,y,A){  # made-up function
  # minimize scaled distance between points x and y
  sum((A[1]*x-A[2]*y)^2)
}
Gc <- function(x,y,A) return(sum(y/3) - sum(x*y))
Hc <- function(x,y,A) return(1-sum(x))

library(nloptr)
y= c(0,1,0)
A= c(10,1)
opt <- nloptr(x0=rep(1/3,3), eval_f=F, lb = rep(0.05,3), ub = rep(1,3), 
              eval_g_ineq = Gc, eval_g_eq = Hc, 
              opts = list(algorithm="NLOPT_GN_ISRES",maxeval=100000), y=y, A=A)
opt$solution
# [1] 0.2990463 0.4004237 0.3005300
```

Comment: If we remove the power 2 in the objective function (i.e. `sum((A[1]*x-A[2]*y))`), why we get different optimal parameter solution for different runnings?